# Regex in notepad ++ add text in end of random number

Tags: notepad++, regex

```
Book 28, Number 3846:
we can go to school today
Book 27, Number 3847:
he is very sick
Book 28, Number 3848:
today is holday
Book 22, Number 3849:
hello my name is abc
Book 28, Number 3850:
thank you dear
Book 28, Number 3851:
what is your name
```

How can I use the RegEx in notepad to add some text in the line of books?

Book # are random, similarly the value after number is also random. I want to make them like this.

```
 Book 28, Number 3846: ###
we can go to school today
 Book 28, Number 3847: ###
he is very sick
 Book 28, Number 3848: ###
today is holday
 Book 28, Number 3849: ###
hello my name is abc
 Book 28, Number 3850: ###
thank you dear
 Book 28, Number 3851: ###
what is your name
```

Comment: Match digits `\d`, use something like RegEx101 to verify your expression on some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all lines start with Book that needs text appending while the other lines do not start with Book, the following regex could be used:

Search for:    `(^Book \d.+$)`
Replace with:  `$1 ###`

Explaination:

```
(              )   = Capture group. Everything it finds is stored as $1
 ^                 = This must occur at the start of the line.
  Book             = Match the word Book, followed by a space
       \d          = The next character(s) must be a digit.
          .+       = The next characters must be anything
             $     = Until the end of the line is reached.
```

By replacing it with $1 your text, the same text will be appended to every line that starts with Book number.

Comment: I tried the same  But it Shows can't find the text (^Book \d.+$)

Comment: Make sure you select regex at the bottom. If it still doesn't work, then the example you gave does not match your actual file.